# Preview a Rails partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, partials

When designing a partial, it would be nice to see what it looks like.

I would like to know - is there a convention for previewing partials in isolation within the browser?

Presumably you could create a special controller that supplies locals and does the rendering - but I would like to know if there is a conventional way.

I am using Rails 4

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of just rendering the partial with a collection in your views, the normal way ?

Comment: There is no conventional way, because its not really convention. The partial may look completely different depending on what view you are rendering it in, css. Render it in the view it's supposed to go in, then apply it to the other views. On a personal level, I feel like you shouldn't really set out to build a partial, build what you need then refactor parts into the partials you need/want.

Comment: @DickieBoy - a partial (e.g. an audio player) could be reused in many different views, or all over a site. It could also have it's own dedicated styles. With this in mind I would like to design it in isolation, without the distraction of the rest of the layout.

Comment: The question is - is there a convention?

Comment: @Bungus I believe I answered the question. Also, why build a partial in isolation when you may end up duplicating styles or having the styles you do apply to it overwritten when it gets placed in situ.